# Get rid of script error in my webbrowser

Tags: c#, forms, webbrowser-control

i have created a webbrowser that goes straight to a website as soon as my program loads but i get a script error message saying "A script error has occured on this page - would you like to continue running scripts on this page ?"

i have researched and found that i needed to enter

```
enter code here  
private void button122_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser2.Navigate(textBox2.Text);
        webBrowser2.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

and it removed 4/5 errors but 1 error still arises after loading my program can some one please help me out im new ive looked at google and youtube and here but still only can find that ScripterrorsSuppressed = true is the way to remove script errors but it didnt get rid of them all it leaves 1 error when i run it.

Comment: ok so i did some more reading from a question on this site and found other people having this problem and they changed the script error debugging to off in the internet explorer options and disable script error notifications so i did this and still i have the script error message appearing when my program starts up my webbrowser ? and also say i give this program to someone and they know nothing about computers therefore wont have internet options set correctly then my program will have lots of script errors how can i fix this please

Comment: I don't think you're giving enough information for anyone to be of assistance. :/